# How to create a for loop to loop through JSON.stringified values determining "paste tabs" for values

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

**Update**: I need to check if a unique value is already in the pasteTab's appropriate column. My code for that is --

```
 for (a = 0; a<coldChainRange.length;a++){
    var fillWeeks = coldChainRange[a][12]
    **var rxNumbers = coldChainRange[a][0]**
    var pasteTab = ss.getSheetByName(fillWeeks)
    //var range = pasteTab.getRange('A2:P'+pasteTab.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues()
    **var array = [];
    array.push(rxNumbers)**
    Logger.log(array)
    //Logger.log(fillWeeks)
    if(fillWeeks != "Need Days Supply"){
        if (pasteTab !== null && **array.indexOf(pasteTab[a][0]==-1**)){
          var patientInfo = ([coldChainRange[a][0],coldChainRange[a][1],coldChainRange[a][2],coldChainRange[a][3],coldChainRange[a][4],
                              coldChainRange[a][5],coldChainRange[a][6],coldChainRange[a][7],coldChainRange[a][8],coldChainRange[a][9],
                              coldChainRange[a][10],coldChainRange[a][11],coldChainRange[a][12],coldChainRange[a][13],coldChainRange[a][14]])
          pasteTab.appendRow(patientInfo)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I need to have the info not be appended if a number is already in the column, however I think the loop is iterating the length of the "pasteTab" which is determined by a week number which is two characters long

How can I create a loop that will go read JSON.stringifed values?
I am trying to loop through cell values to determine where the information should be appended to. For example, if a cell had a value of "23" it would be appended to the 23 tab.

```
function sendToFillWeek() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var coldChainPasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName('from looker')
  var coldChainRange = coldChainPasteSheet.getRange('A2:P' + coldChainPasteSheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues()

  for (a = 0; a<coldChainRange.length;a++){
    var fillWeeks = JSON.stringify(coldChainRange[a][12])   
    var pasteTab = ss.getSheetByName(fillWeeks)
    Logger.log(pasteTab)
    }}
```

This is my code so far for determining the appropriate sheet. The fillWeeks produces the values I need, however the pasteTab outputs all "null" values.

```
    for(b=0; b<fillWeeks.length;b++){
      (if fillWeeks !== "Need Day Supply" ){

        var patientInfo = ([coldChainRange[a][0],coldChainRange[a][1],coldChainRange[a][2],coldChainRange[a][3],coldChainRange[a][4],
                            coldChainRange[a][5],coldChainRange[a][6],coldChainRange[a][7],coldChainRange[a][8],coldChainRange[a][9],
                            coldChainRange[a][10],coldChainRange[a][11],coldChainRange[a][12],coldChainRange[a][13],coldChainRange[a][14],
                            coldChainRange[a][15]])
        pasteTab.appendRow(patientInfo)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially, I would like the information to be appended the appropriate tabs.

Comment: JSON.stringify() is for converting valid JavaScript objects into strings - not sure why you use this method on sheet values. The 'getDisplayValues()' method already returns the array of strings

Comment: Yeah I realized that it was only looping through the length of the strings characters....

Comment: for (a = 0; a<coldChainRange.length;a++){
    var fillWeeks = coldChainRange[a][12]
    var pasteTab = ss.getSheetByName(fillWeeks)
    var object = createObject(pasteTab)
    

is what I used to get the proper output

Comment: @AntonDementiev can u help me with this updated problem?

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking programming questions that may be of value to others who are dealing with the same problem, not for debugging someone else's code  line by line. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AntonDementiev I feel like this is not a unique problem, nor one that will never be asked again, but ok thank you for your advice